# High Message Push Rate from Google Cloud Pubsub Subscription to Cloud Function Despite High Error Rate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Why is my Google Cloud PubSub subscription pushing messages to a Cloud Function at such a high rate despite a high error rate?

Here's the subscription configuration:

```
% gcloud pubsub subscriptions describe [REDACTED_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME]
ackDeadlineSeconds: 300
deadLetterPolicy:
  deadLetterTopic: projects/[REDACTED]/topics/[REDACTED]
  maxDeliveryAttempts: 100
expirationPolicy: {}
filter: attributes.env = "production"
messageRetentionDuration: 604800s
name: projects/[REDACTED]/subscriptions/[REDACTED_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME]
pushConfig:
  pushEndpoint: https://[REDACTED].cloudfunctions.net/[REDACTED_FUNCTION_NAME]
  ...
retryPolicy:
  maximumBackoff: 600s
  minimumBackoff: 30s
state: ACTIVE
topic: projects/[REDACTED]/topics/[REDACTED_TOPIC_NAME]
```

And the cloud function configuration:

```
% gcloud functions describe [FUNCTION_NAME]
automaticUpdatePolicy: {}
availableMemoryMb: 1024
buildId: 623c4c9a-a8c5-45eb-b02d-b0db6305f2ea
buildName: projects/[PROJECT_ID]/locations/us-central1/builds/[BUILD_ID]
dockerRegistry: CONTAINER_REGISTRY
entryPoint: run
environmentVariables:
  ...
httpsTrigger:
  securityLevel: SECURE_OPTIONAL
  url: https://us-central1-[PROJECT].cloudfunctions.net/[FUNCTION_NAME]
ingressSettings: ALLOW_ALL
labels:
  deployment-tool: cli-gcloud
maxInstances: 5
name: projects/[PROJECT]/locations/us-central1/functions/[FUNCTION_NAME]
runtime: nodejs18
serviceAccountEmail: [PROJECT]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
status: ACTIVE
timeout: 300s
versionId: '59'
vpcConnector: projects/[PROJECT]/locations/us-central1/connectors/mcfx-identity
vpcConnectorEgressSettings: PRIVATE_RANGES_ONLY
```

During a specific analysis period, I observed:

- 2.7 million 429 errors (indicating too many requests) from the Cloud Function. [image: error logs]
- 195k requests handled successfully by the Cloud Function. [image: success logs]
- The subscription continued sending well over 100 messages per second, despite over 90% of these delivery attempts failing. [image: push chart]
- The Cloud Function's throughput maxed at around 11 messages per second.

Here's a summary dashboard [image: dashboard]

This documentation https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#push_backoff says that pubsub is supposed to backoff in such scenarios.

This documentation https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#delivery_rate says that "The push window increases on any successful delivery and decreases on any failure" but it seems like the push window is failing to decrease in this case.

Any insights on why the push rate remains high despite a significant failure rate, and how to mitigate this issue?

Comment: What's your Cloud Functions configuration? Did you set any limits? (Max instance) How long is the message processing? What's your ideal throughput to absorb all your messages??

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I updated the description to include more of the function definition. It's limited to 5 instances to avoid overwhelming the database.

Comment: 5 instances?? does your database have no more than 5 connections? It's weird... In any case, it seems consistent: processing 2 messages per second, per instance, lot of 429 because you limit the Cloud Functions scaling. But indeed, I don't know why PubSub sends and resends in loop all the messages with backoff.

Comment: Each instance is processing up to 10,000 records so 5 instances is enough to keep up with demand

Comment: 10,000 records per second? Is it 1 record per message?

Comment: Yes to 10k records per second. But each message has up to 10k ids, so up to 10k records per message.

Comment: If Google Cloud try to deliver 100+ message per second and you can process only 10, there is a misconfiguration (or design issue) somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Picking up on @[guillaume blaquiere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere)'s comment regarding misconfiguration, I also believe that is the case between your Cloud Function and Pub/Sub configuration.

The high push rate can be linked to the [retry settings](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#subscription_retry_policy) of your Pub/Sub especially if the messages are not properly processed in your Cloud Function. Review how you [handle message failures](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures), consider [increasing your Cloud Function's max instance value](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/max-instances#limits_best_practices) and Pub/Sub's `minimumBackoff` as it can increase retry attempts during sudden burst of messages, contributing to your high push rate, if they are set too low.

> Note: This feature is independent from [Push backoff](https://Note:%20This%20feature%20is%20independent%20from%20Push%20backoff.%20You%20can%20use%20these%20two%20features%20together%20to%20better%20control%20the%20flow%20of%20messages.%20In%20this%20case,%20the%20total%20delay%20is%20the%20maximum%20combined%20value%20of%20both%20the%20push%20backoff%20value%20and%20the%20retry%20policy%20value.%20If%20you%27re%20noticing%20issues%20with%20message%20delivery,%20double%20check%20how%20your%20retry%20policy%20is%20interacting%20with%20push%20backoff.). You can use these two features together to better control the flow of messages. In this case, the total delay is the maximum combined value of both the push backoff value and the retry policy value. If you're noticing issues with message delivery, double check how your retry policy is interacting with push backoff.

Comment: Increasing max instances is not an option. Can you elaborate on how `minimumBackoff` interacts with the the push backoff?

Comment: Official documents says: (1) Push backoff uses an exponential backoff algorithm to determine the delay Pub/Sub that uses between sending messages. (2) Exponential backoff lets you add progressively longer delays between retry attempts. After the first delivery failure, Pub/Sub waits for a minimum backoff time before retrying. With the 30s minbackoff config in your retry policy and the 10K records/ sec message you mentioned with guillaume blaquiere, you can somehow expect a high push rate because it only needs a short 30s before Pub/Sub's first few retry attempts on those failed messages.

Comment: I experimented with increasing minimumBackoff to it's maximum value of 600s and decreasing to it's minimum value of 10s and it made no difference to this behavior.